# How do I model a sequence such that it increases by half of the previous number?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been trying so many combinations of this sequence

let's say it starts at 2, 3, 3.5, 3.75, 3.875
so +1, +.5, + .25, + .125, etc

I just cant find some expression that satisfies this starting at 0 or 1, I believe this would be geometric

I've tried 2 + n/2, 2 + 1/n^2, 2 + 1/2^n * n, but each time it doesn't get fully satisfied. I need to find some way to multiply by the new half n yet also adding it to the original n. Any tips?

Comment: So...you want $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+\frac {a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}}2=\frac 32\times a_{n-1}-\frac 12\times a_{n-2}$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your additions are a geometric series which you can sum.  The ratio is $\frac 12$ and the starting value is $1$, so the overall sequence term is $2+\frac {1-\frac 1{2^n}}{1-\frac 12}$ where the first term is $n=0$